# puppet server not able to provision itself - certificate verify failed

Tags: certificate, puppet, verify

I installed a new Puppet Server (Version 6.11) on CentOS 8 to get rid of our old 3.8 Installation on CentOS 6.

After the migration of all of our modules and testing them on a CentOS 7 and 8 Server, I now wanted to add the Puppet Server itself as a node.

While the CentOS 7 and 8 Testserver are running fine, I am not able to get the puppet Server itself running as also a puppet client.

I added it as a node with just one Module and tried to run puppet agent:

```
[root@puppetmaster /]# puppet agent --test --server puppetmaster.th  
Info: csr_attributes file loading from /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/csr_attributes.yaml
Info: Creating a new SSL certificate request for puppetmaster.th
Info: Certificate Request fingerprint (SHA256): E8:F3:69:50:53:43:32:4F:D8:D1:EF:18:17:98:70:15:3C:3B:B6:A1:6B:CA:0F:F0:A4:C3:EF:FE:3B:C5:3C:01
Error: certificate verify failed [unable to get certificate CRL for CN=puppetmaster.th]
Error: Could not run: certificate verify failed [unable to get certificate CRL for CN=puppetmaster.th]
```

I tried deleting the Certs in `/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/` as well as in `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl` and `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/sslmaster/`.

I always get the same result. Looking into `puppetserver ca list --all` I get a 3 existing Server:

```
Signed Certificates:
centos7.th            (SHA256)  A8:EF:33:B6:92:F2:B7:42:DA:F8:B3:B5:67:DD:5A:68:6E:C1:40:97:23:B7:35:7C:A4:36:52:EB:3A:0D:C9:7F
centos8.th            (SHA256)  35:CE:E7:7D:44:5B:93:C0:80:44:DB:75:BE:9C:CF:04:81:02:00:D7:49:D7:51:52:47:38:CA:E6:77:1D:01:19
puppetmaster.th       (SHA256)  7E:F5:A4:24:47:F6:90:2D:54:BB:D0:A9:5E:EF:B8:61:C9:E9:D4:7F:AE:68:82:7A:6A:C3:13:F9:21:72:3F:3F     alt names: ["DNS:puppetmaster.th", "DNS:puppetmaster", "DNS:puppetmaster.th"]   authorization extensions: [pp_cli_auth: true]
```

The 2 Testservers are still running fine (besides I had to of course add them again after deleting all certs).

Now I am a little confused how to add the puppet server itself as a working agent (which does work fine in the old setup).

Comment: If your master is (was) already running, then it already has a cert.  Unless you take explicit steps to arrange differently, the agent can and probably should use the existing cert to identify itself to the master.  Something is screwy if it tried to generate a new cert at all.

Comment: Additionally, do check your nodes.  It seems likely that deleting your existing certs on the master will have caused it to be unable to authenticate itself to client nodes.

Comment: as i said, i had to re-add my already existing nodes after i deleted the certs. They are working fine. I was under same impression that the puppet server client should use the already existing cert, but it does not (also re-creating that cert did not help)

Comment: found the solution myself. The server is running with "ssldir=/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/sslmaster". When trying to start the agent on the server, it creates a new private key in "/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl" for an already existing node. I now copied the already existing ssl key from "/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/sslmaster/private_keys" to "/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private_keys" and its working